# How to use to in radius command for turtles to seek food and how to regenerate food over time in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to do the following in NetLogo:

1. Get turtles (Elephants) to seek food
2. Ask plants to reproduce slowly over time on each side, one side before the other
3. Keep turtles (Elephants) to stay within world boundary
4. Keep turtles (Elephants) upright

What I would basically like to do is have our turtles (elephants) eat food on one side and seek food to cross to the other side. They will die if they get hit by a car. We want them to cross back and forth between sides so that they all die over time. We have tried to use the seek food primitive but is does not work for our simulation. We have also had the turtles stay within the world using the bounce primitive but with this current code they tend to move everywhere once again. As for the food regeneration, we have tried to use the hatch function but that also does not work.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Here is our code for the simulation:

```
breed [ elephants elephant ]
breed [ cars car ]
breed [ plants plant ]

turtles-own [
  speed
  speed-limit
  speed-min
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-elephants
  setup-cars
  setup-plants
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    ifelse (pycor > -2) and (pycor < 2)
    [ set pcolor black ]
    [ set pcolor green ]
  ]
end

to setup-elephants
  ask n-of number-of-elephants (patches with [ pycor < -4 ])
  [ sprout-elephants 1
    [ set shape "elephant"
      set color 4
      set size 4
    ]
  ]

end

to setup-cars
  ask n-of number-of-cars (patches with [ pcolor = black ])
  [ sprout-cars 1
    [ set shape "car"
      set color 105
      set size 2
      set heading 90
    ]
  ]
end

to setup-plants
  ask n-of number-of-plants (patches with [ pcolor = green ])
  [ sprout-plants 1
    [ set shape "plant"
      set color 62
      set size 1
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask elephants [
    bounce forward 1
  ]
  ask cars [
    set xcor random-xcor
    set heading 90
    forward 1
    move-elephants
    move-cars
    eat-plants
    kill-elephants
  ]
end

to bounce
  if abs pxcor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading ( - heading ) ]
  if abs pycor = max-pycor
    [ set heading ( 180 - heading ) ]
end

to move-elephants
  ask elephants [
    right random 360
    forward 1
  ]
end

to move-cars
  set speed 0.1
  set speed-limit 0.1
end

to eat-plants
  ask elephants
  [ let prey one-of plants-here
    if prey != nobody [ask prey [die]]
  ]
end

to kill-elephants
  ask cars
  [ let prey one-of elephants-here 
    if prey != nobody [ask prey [die]]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with this code so I am going to try and get rid of the more obvious logical issues and see if that allows you to focus on a specific question. Note that you should really be building your code more gradually - add one behaviour (eg move elephants, move cars, eat food or whatever) and make sure it works before adding the next behaviour.

1. Your go procedure doesn't have a `tick` for time passage
2. Your go procedure has each car randomly move all the elephants, so they are moving multiple times
3. Your car speeds and speed limits are being set to the same value each tick and never changed
4. You have nested `ask cars [ ask elephants [ <do stuff> ] ]` for eating plants and killing elephants, which will make these happen many times each tick

Fixing just those problems, gets this (note that I replaced slider inputs with numbers so  you will have to change them back). This should fix the things you mentioned in your comments. You will have to ask a specific question about whatever else it is you are trying to fix.

```
breed [ elephants elephant ]
breed [ cars car ]
breed [ plants plant ]

turtles-own
[ speed
  speed-limit
  speed-min
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-elephants
  setup-cars
  setup-plants
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask elephants
  [ bounce
    forward 1
  ]
  ask cars [ forward 1 ]
  move-elephants
  eat-plants
  kill-elephants
  tick
end

to bounce
  if abs pxcor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading ( - heading ) ]
  if abs pycor = max-pycor
    [ set heading ( 180 - heading ) ]
end

to move-elephants
  ask elephants
  [ right random 360
    forward 1
  ]
end

to eat-plants
  ask elephants
  [ let prey one-of plants-here
    if prey != nobody [ask prey [die]]
  ]
end

to kill-elephants
  ask cars
  [ let prey one-of elephants-here 
    if prey != nobody [ask prey [die]]
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    ifelse (pycor > -2) and (pycor < 2)
    [ set pcolor black ]
    [ set pcolor green ]
  ]
end

to setup-elephants
  ask n-of 20 (patches with [ pycor < -4 ])
  [ sprout-elephants 1
    [ set shape "wolf"
      set color 4
      set size 4
    ]
  ]

end

to setup-cars
  ask n-of 20 (patches with [ pcolor = black ])
  [ sprout-cars 1
    [ set shape "car"
      set color 105
      set size 2
      set heading 90
      set speed 0.1
      set speed-limit 0.1
    ]
  ]
end

to setup-plants
  ask n-of 50 (patches with [ pcolor = green ])
  [ sprout-plants 1
    [ set shape "plant"
      set color 62
      set size 1
    ]
  ]
end
```